# Rspec can't find method in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My helper calls a method defined in ApplicationController as a helper method. When application is in debug or production mode this schema works fine, but when I attempt to run tests for this helper, it causes `NoMethodError: undefined method method_name`
What else I have to require/include?

Answer (score 0):

Move helper method into helpers/application_helper.rb, and add

```
helper ApplicationHelper
```

in ApplicationController

Answer (score -1):

create a folder called `spec/support`

inside create `utilities.rb`

in `utilities.rb`

insert the method from your ApplicationController.

Comment: Sorry, just realised that you said ApplicationController, not ApplicationHelper.  Just drop the helper method from Application Controller into utilities.rb

Comment: Do you suggest to copy and paste the whole text of the method disregarding the DRY?

Comment: Without sharing you're test code it's a bit difficult to help further.  There is some info about testing helpers here though https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-13/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec which seems to state that methods in controllers are not included